# ArcGIS PRO Memory Leak Caused By Single Feature Class

Tags: snapping, arcgis-pro, memory, attribute-index

I use a combination of ArcMap and PRO on a daily basis. It doesn't appear that many people are using PRO yet based on the lack of documentation online. All of layers are feature classes stored in geodatabases.

I understand that PRO uses a lot of RAM. My computer at work has 8GB. PRO normally uses between 1-3.5GB. This week I have been working in project in which over the course of a couple minutes my RAM usage will start at around 1GB and wind up at 7GB (caps there because my other processes are using the last gig). The program is virtually unusable at that point, with 99% of my computer's resources being used. Additionally coinciding with this problem, the snapping feature is not correctly working. I'm using the same snapping settings I always use, but have to hover over a point or line for 10-15 seconds until the snap registers. Once the RAM reaches that max, the snapping no longer works.

I spent hours trying to figure out the issue. I updated my drivers, turned off labeling, and removed all rasters to try and deduce the problem. I noticed that one feature was correctly snapping. If I moved any non-working feature class (FC) to the top of the ToC hierarchy they began working correctly. I realized every FC below a certain polygon FC was not snapping. I removed the FC and snapping began working correctly, and the memory leak stopped. The only difference I notice between the FC in question and every other FC is the indexing. The working FCs are all using FDO_OBJECTID for attribute index. The problem FC is using FDO_OBJECTID, but also has FDO_GlobalID listed. Is there any way indexing can be causing this leak? Has anyone else experienced this problem?

**TLDR:** One feature class in my ArcGIS PRO project was causing a rapid memory leak, making the program unusable. It was also causing the snapping feature to not work correctly. Removing the feature from the project corrected the situation. My only hypothesis for the problem is related to indexing.

Comment: I completely disagree. Although the problem is obviously a bug with the software, my intent in posting on here was to see if anyone also has this bug, if anyone knows what causes this bug, and if anyone has a method of fixing this bug. ESRI support will do absolutely nothing to solve any of their bugs individually. Why would I ask them when open sourcing questions will have better results?

Comment: What you are experiencing is software bug (memory leak) it is advisable to inform the software vendor (esri in this case) once a ticket is assigned and they have confirmed the issue you have, it will become a development ticket, and eventually patched, from 15 years of experience with this vendor this can take 6 months - 2 years to fix.

Comment: What version of Pro? Are you in Map or Globe view? Can you share this particular featureclass?

Comment: Did you try the same combination of layers and extent in ArcMap with different results?  Did you rebuild the spatial index and repair geometry?  Does the problem layer have a huge number of vertices, since that can overwhelm snapping?

Comment: Weirdly enough, it's unfortunate that it's not crashing to the point you could send in a report. The Pro team assiduously chases down crashes. I looked in the bug queue for memory leak with snapping or editing but didn't see anything similar. Another possibility of a fix--try importing the feature class data to a new fc.

Comment: Tech Support is the keeper of the list of others with that same problem, has the connections to the developers who can tell what is causing it, and are the only ones authorized to distribute QFEs.  Support doesn't ever fix bugs, but they do validate reproducible cases and help set priority (memory leaks get a fairly high default priority).  You might not get a patch every time, but **if the issue can be reproduced before code freeze**, a fix in the next release is far more likely if you contact Tech Support than if you don't.

Comment: [**We are not a GIS Software Support Site.** We encourage you to seek official routes for support for specific issues you may have.](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)